# I don't understand this sentence

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, clauses

From the book *Mastering Regular Expressions, 3rd Edition*:

> **The story that is the first six chapters form the basis for the last four, covering specifics of Perl, Java, .NET, and PHP**. To help you get the most from each part, I've used cross references liberally, and I've worked hard to make the index as useful as possible. (Over 1,200 cross references are sprinkled throughout the book; they are often presented as *-->* followed by a page number.)

I can't make grammatical sense of the first sentence. It seems that the subject is ***the story***. The rest reads ***that is the first six chapters form the basis for the last four, covering specifics of Perl, Java, .NET, and PHP*** and seems to be a dependent clause. But where is the subject's verb? ...actually, the sentence is very confusing.

Comment: Definitely a confusing sentence without commas, and it should be forms not form. *The story, that is the first six chapters, **forms** the basis for the last four, covering specifics of Perl, Java, .Net, and PHP.*

Comment: I think we're going to be seeing quite a few questions from this book, because the writing style is terrible :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The story that is the first six chapters form the basis for the last four, covering specifics of Perl, Java, .NET, and PHP

Subject is *story* and the main verb is *form*, and it should be *forms* to agree with singular *story*.  This would make it somewhat clearer.

The text "*that is the first six chapters*" is a clause qualifying *story*.  The clause ends after "chapters."

Answer (score 2):

It's actually less a qualifying clause than a (crazy, hyphenated) noun:

The story-that-is-the-first-six-chapters form**s**....